# 802.1X Auth for Clients and Servers

Tags: switch, router, vlan, radius, ieee-802.1x

I'm about to introduce 802.1X Authentication to my current network for wifi and wired connections:

My Setup:
I have a Windows Domain Controller and I wanted to use the Network Policy Service for RADIUS User-Based-Authentication since all the windows clients are already part of it.

I was just wondering how to authenticate all the server systems (linux and windows) that I've got because some are not part of the domain and i don't want to join them all. I will use RADIUS-Auth for dynamic VLAN assignment and my idea was to reserve some switchports the server systems which will use mac-based authentication and assign the vlan static via port for these systems.

Do you guys have any other solution to fix the static vlan assignment for the servers?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Simply don't authenticate server ports - you know who's connecting anyway.

Comment: So simply assign the vlan for the ports where servers connect to?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to authenticate servers. We have implemented 802.1x but excluded server, printer and IoT devices. They’re on a separate Vlan.

Answer (score 1):

Server port Authentication is not required. You are in separate VLAN. You can bind/assign switch port to each servers. If you assign switch port to each device, you know exactly which device is connected.